# Test a site with a static subdomain locally

Tags: subdomain, testing, static-content

How can I test a site that uses one or more static domains for serving images locally?

e.g.

- domain.tld with images servered from static.domain.tld
- Local working copy of the site on WAMP checked out from SVN: URLs will be pointing at static.domain.tld rather than static.domain.local

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault.  The basic idea is to use your hosts file to map all the domains to 127.0.0.1, then use name-based VirtualHosts (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) to distinguish in Apache.

Comment: What is a static domain actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but you could always put entries in your hosts file if it's a question of resolving static.domain.tld, domain.tld, etc.

```
%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:

static.domain.tld   127.0.0.1
someotherstatic.domain.tld   127.0.0.1
```